# Select persons which have overlap with other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I didn't even know how to come up with a good title, so I hope I can describe my problem in a right way :)

So I have a person table, and it has a N:N relationship with keywords via the table PersonKeywords.

Then I also have a Search table, and it also has a N:N relationship with keywords via the table SearchKeywords.

Now the person can have a relationship with keyword A and B, and the search record can have a relationship with the keywords A and C.

Now I want the person in my resultset, because it has at least one (in this 'A') of the keywords the search record has.

I also want the person who has 'A', the one with 'C', the one with 'A' and 'C', but not the one with only B.

So it's a match on two lists, but I don't know where to start to create such a statement...

Comment: I find it a bit hard to understand. Would it be possible to show an image of the DB structure or something like that?

Comment: I understand the relationships, but what table are you trying to query against? Do you want a list of "Search"es, or "Person"s?

Comment: This is best described by including some sample data and the results that you would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have three people...

```
declare @persons table (id int identity(1,1), name varchar(10))
insert @persons (name) values ('Babs'),('Ken'),('Neville'),('Sue')
```

Babs has A and B, Ken has A and C, Neville has B only and Sue has C only

```
declare @personkeywords table (personid int, keyword varchar(5))
insert @personkeywords values (1,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'a'),(2,'c'),(3,'b'),(4,'c')
```

The search is for A or C

```
declare @searchkeywords table (searchid int, keyword varchar(5))
insert @searchkeywords values (1,'a'),(1,'c')
```

So...

```
select distinct persons.*
from @persons persons
     inner join @personkeywords personkeywords on persons.id = personkeywords.personid
     inner join @searchkeywords searchkeywords on personkeywords.keyword = searchkeywords.keyword
where 
     searchkeywords.searchid = 1
```

Gives

```
1     Babs
2     Ken
4     Sue
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't have very much information to work with, the following should at least help you...

```
SELECT s.SearchID, k.Keyword, p.PersonID, p.Name
FROM Search s
INNER JOIN SearchKeywords sk ON s.SearchID = sk.SearchID
INNER JOIN Keywords k ON sk.KeywordID = k.KeywordID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PersonKeywords pk ON k.KeywordID = pk.KeywordID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Person p ON pk.PersonID = p.PersonID
WHERE k.Keyword = 'mykeyword'
GROUP BY s.SearchID, k.Keyword, p.PersonID, p.Name
```